# EnterCriticalSection blocks forever

Tags: windows, multithreading, critical-section

When running our `x64` application on `Windows 10`, we have a problem with
void `WINAPI` **EnterCriticalSection** (`__inout LPCRITICAL_SECTION lpCriticalSection`);

**Scenario:**

A global `CRITICAL_SECTION` object is used by `8` worker threads.

Sometimes the call of `EnterCriticalSection` **blocks** one of the worker threads **forever**, even if the critical section is unlocked and free as you can see here:

> - LockCount = -1
> - RecursionCount = 0
> - OwningThread = 0x0000000000000000
> - LockSemaphore = 0xffffffffffffffff
> - SpinCount = 4000

The thread does not run into the critical section for unknown reasons.

Changing the SpinCount value does not help.

`EnterCriticalSection ()` is balanced with `LeaveCriticalSection ()` and it is not deleted in between.

This problem is **not present** when running the same code on **Windows 7**.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 09/11/2015:**
Since we still did not found a solution for this problem yet (appears only on Windows 10) and everything looks good in the structures and algorithms, we found a workaround:

The hack is a different kind of initialization of some parts of your software, so that the call of this specific lock is NOT needed at all now during runtime.

Comment: "It's a bug in the OS" never gets you anywhere.  So you have to look for the bug in your code.  A pretty standard one is having the CS heavily contested by all these threads and hoping they are treated fairly, each getting a chance to acquire the CS.  There is no fairness.

Comment: LockCount = -1?  I don't have a Windows machine to test on, but might that indicate the critical section has been destroyed or not initialized?

Comment: IIRC, the most common cause of this sort of a problem is a thread releasing the critical section when it doesn't own it.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541979(v=vs.85).aspx LockCount = -1 indicates that it's an unlocked critical section (EnterCriticalSection was not called on it)